# Running Pootle server under Apache with mod_wsgi on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, django, wsgi

I have successfully installed a pootle server in a localhost environment using the django default server following the instructions found here: http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/stable-2.8.x/server/installation.html

Then I successfully setup nginx as reverse proxy server following the instructions here:  http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/stable-2.8.x/server/web.html#proxying-with-nginx

Then I successfully migrated the database from SQLite to MySQL following the instructions here: http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/stable-2.8.x/server/mysql_installation.html#mysql-installation

Now I wanted to take the next step and run the pootle server under apache with mod_wsgi so as not to use the default django server, as I get ready for a fully fledged production server. I followed the instructions here: http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/stable-2.8.x/server/web.html#apache-with-mod-wsgi

I have succeeded in loading the start page, but I'm having trouble when I try to login. I'm getting this error in the chrome console:

***`vendor.min.ce9c05c2.js:25 POST http://pootle.localhost/var/www/vhosts/pootle/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/accounts/login/?next=%2F 402 (Payment Required)`***

The start page is showing just fine at http://pootle.localhost so I'm pretty sure the assets are being loaded directly without any trouble with the Apache instruction:

```
Alias /assets /var/www/vhosts/pootle/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/assets/
```

It seems that there is something wrong between apache and wsgi because I don't think I should be seeing **/var/www/vhosts/pootle/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle** in the URL of the POST ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out the problem. And I should kick myself for it.
I had this at the end of my pootle.conf :

```
# - Include the following settings in your custom Pootle settings:
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/var/www/vhosts/pootle/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/'
POOTLE_ENABLE_API = True
```

FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME obviously should have been:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/'
```

Problem solved, dumb mistake on my part.